# CSS height element ignored

Tags: html, css, datagrid, dojo

I have two DataGrid tables that I want to make 200px tall but something is overriding the height in my css.  Currently the tables are two completely different sizes when displayed.

Tables:

```
<table  dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="dnToCountDiv" data-dojo-id="dnToCountDiv" columnReordering="true"
                            sortFields="['extension','totalcalls','totaloutboundcalls','internaloutboundcalls','localoutboundcalls','longdistanceoutboundcalls','internationaloutboundcalls','totalinboundcalls','inboundinternalcalls','inboundexternalcalls']"
                            rowWidth="100%"
                            noDataMessage="<span class='dojoxGridNoData'>No Calls to Show</span>"
                            class="statisticsTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th field="extension" width="100%" >Extension</th>
                                <th field="totalcalls" width="100%" >Total</th>
                                <th field="totaloutboundcalls" width="100%" > Total Out</th>
                                <th field="internaloutboundcalls" width="100%" >Internal Out</th>
                                <th field="localoutboundcalls" width="100%" >Local Out</th>
                                <th field="longdistanceoutboundcalls" width="100%" >Long Dist Out</th>
                                <th field="internationaloutboundcalls" width="100%" >Internat. Out</th>
                                <th field="totalinboundcalls" width="100%" >Total In</th>
                                <th field="inboundinternalcalls" width="100%" >Internal In</th>
                                <th field="inboundexternalcalls" width="100%" >External In</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>

                    <!-- dn to call time table -->
                    <h3>Call Time Per Extension
                        <button  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="call_time_help_button" data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'helpIconClass'">Column Key
                            <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" >
                                alert("call Time help pressed");
                            </script>
                        </button></h3>
                    <table  dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="dnToTimeDiv" data-dojo-id="dnToTimeDiv" columnReordering="true"
                            sortFields="['extension','totalcalls','totaloutboundcalls','internaloutboundcalls','localoutboundcalls','longdistanceoutboundcalls','internationaloutboundcalls','totalinboundcalls','inboundinternalcalls','inboundexternalcalls']"
                            rowWidth="100%"
                            noDataMessage="<span class='dojoxGridNoData'>No Calls to Show</span>"
                            class="statisticsTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th field="extension" width="100%" >Extension</th>
                                <th field="totalcalls" width="100%" >Total</th>
                                <th field="totaloutboundcalls" width="100%" > Total Out</th>
                                <th field="internaloutboundcalls" width="100%" >Internal Out</th>
                                <th field="localoutboundcalls" width="100%" >Local Out</th>
                                <th field="longdistanceoutboundcalls" width="100%" >Long Dist Out</th>
                                <th field="internationaloutboundcalls" width="100%" >Internat. Out</th>
                                <th field="totalinboundcalls" width="100%" >Total In</th>
                                <th field="inboundinternalcalls" width="100%" >Internal In</th>
                                <th field="inboundexternalcalls" width="100%" >External In</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.statisticsTable {
width: 800px;
height: 200px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#C1C1C1;
```

}

The Borders and such are getting properly added so it sees the CSS.  When I open firebug though I get the following when inspecting the html on one of the tables.  It acknowledges that element.style is overriding the height.

[image]

How would I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: only `!important` rules are stronger than the `style` attribute.

Comment: ahhh perfect that fixed it thank you.  If you would like the score submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `style` attribute can only be overriden by using `!important`.

```
.statisticsTable {
  height: 200px !important;
  /* ... */
}
```

You should avoid `!important` at all costs, however, as `!important` can only be overridden by `!important` (plaguing your entire stylesheet with it), inline styles can only override `!important` styles if they are themselves `!important`, and `!important` inline styles cannot be overriden by CSS at all. If you can avoid creating the style attribute that you need to override in the first place, you should definitely do it.

Comment: Should be mentioned that use of `!important` indicates poor CSS.

Comment: @AdamWaite Didn't I imply that by saying that style attributes shouldn't be used? If you know a nice way to formulate it better, you are free to edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: @AdamWaite better now?